# RichTextBox Include Special Characters

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm trying to display the following text in a `RichTextBox`:

`rtxtHL7.Text = "MSH|^~\&|%send%|SCM|%receive%||%date%||ADT^A31|%date%%seq%|D|2.3"`

I have tried using "&" and "&&", that didn't work.

It takes `|,%,^,~` etc. as special characters and does not compile.

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. Could you please clarify it?

Comment: On the click of a button, I want to display the mentioned code in the RichTextBox. However, the required code has lot of characters that the dot net application considers as special characters. You can try doing the same, create a normal application with a button and a richtextbox, and try to display the code mentioned on the button click. It will not compile.

Comment: First, can you link to a screenshot of the output.  Second, is there any reason you cannot use a TextBox for this since you are displaying plain text?

Comment: Please check this screenshot: http://grab.by/zZn8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is a [verbatim literal string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), meaning you want to use the `@` character at the beginning of the string to tell the compiler to treat it as such instead of taking special characters (e.g. `\` escape character) into account:

```
rtxtHL7.Text = @"MSH|^~\&|%send%|SCM|%receive%||%date%||ADT^A31|%date%%seq%|D|2.3";
```